# What does x->a = x->b, ++x++ ->b; do in the given program?

Tags: c

```
int main() 
{
    struct data{
        int a;
        int b;
    }y[4] = {1,10,3,30,2,20,4,40};

    struct data *x = y;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
         x->a = x->b, ++x++ ->b;
         printf("%d%d\t", y[i].a, y[i].b);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

How does this code work?

Comment: Don't change the question after getting answers and comments. And don't make the question to broad. `->` is the structure reference operator ( Google it for more information on that ) and `= { ... }` initializes all the elements of the array with the values in the initializer list. Play with it for a while and you'll get the hang of it :-)

Comment: No professional or enthusiast programmer would care because all such code is garbage, as is this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code in the question is execrable and is of zero, or negative, use to future visitors.

Answer (score 4):

The statement

```
x->a = x->b, ++x++ ->b;  //note the comma operator after x->a = x->b
```

is equivalent to

```
x->a = x->b;     // Assign member `a` to first member of element of array y 
++( (x++) ->b);  // Fetch the member b of element of array y and then increment 
                 // it by 1. Increment `x` by 1 after `b` is fetched.
```

Answer (score 4):

The `++x++` is well defined in this context:

```
++x++->b
```

that is equivalent to:

```
++((x++)->b)
```

This means that two different `x` and `x->b` *lvalues* are incremented, not single one (which would be an UB). You may rewrite it into two statements:

```
++(x->b);
x++;
```

The full expression statement:

```
x->a = x->b, ++x++ ->b;
```

is valid, since there is sequence point (because of comma operator) after `x->a = x->b` is evaluated <strike>(there were no side effects in this one, so result of this subexpression was discarded)</strike>.

Answer (score 1):

This expression

```
x->a = x->b, ++x++ ->b;
```

uses the comma operator and in fact for clarity can be split in two statements

```
x->a = x->b;
++x++ ->b;
```

The second subexpression can be imagine the following way

```
struct data *temp = x;
++x;
++temp->b;
```

that is it increases data member `b` of the structure pointed to by pointer `x` and increases the pointer itself.

So data member `b` of the current structure (object of type struct data) is increased and the pointer will point to the next structure.